# Define StringSet AttributeType when creating DynamoDB table, via the AWS-CLI and with a JSON skeleton

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am trying to define a table for Amazon Web Service DynamoDB from the command line.

I have successfully run `aws dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file://tmp.json` with the following json file:

```
  1 {
  2     "AttributeDefinitions": [
  3         {
  4             "AttributeName": "testCase",
  5             "AttributeType": "S"
  6         },
  7         {
  8             "AttributeName": "cFlags",
  9             "AttributeType": "S"
 10         }
 11     ],
 12     "TableName": "TestTable",
 13     "KeySchema": [
 14         {
 15             "AttributeName": "testCase",
 16             "KeyType": "HASH"
 17         },
 18         {
 19             "AttributeName": "cFlags",
 20             "KeyType": "RANGE"
 21         }
 22     ],
 23     "ProvisionedThroughput": {
 24         "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
 25         "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
 26     }
 27 }
```

However, in pratcice, the `cFlags` attribute is not a string, but rather an unordered set of strings*.  I read [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html) that:

> DynamoDB supports types that represent sets of Number, String, or Binary values.

Yet, I read [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeDefinition.html) that the options for the `AttributeType` field are only the scalar ones:

> AttributeType
>    The data type for the attribute, where:
>
> - S - the attribute is of type String
> - N - the attribute is of type Number
> - B - the attribute is of type Binary
>
>   Type: String
>
>   Valid Values: S | N | B
>
>   Required: Yes

I have tried to define the attribute type of `cFlags` in various ways, none of which seem to work:

- `"AttributeType": [ "S" ]`
- `"AttributeType": "[ S ]"`
- `"AttributeType": "SS"`

Could someone explain what I am not doing right and what is the correct way to do what I want in DynamoDB ?

---

*An example would be the string `-O -Werror` as in the case of a `gcc` invocation such as `gcc -O -Werror src_file.c`.  It makes no difference whether `gcc` in invoked with `-O -Werror` or `-Werror -O`.  So in my use case, the unordered set `[ "-O", "-Werror" ]` defines one potential value of the `cFlags` attribute.

Comment: `"AttributeType": "SS"` was inspired by this documentation:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html

Answer (score 4):

The key attributes of DynamoDB should be a scalar type. You can have a non-key attribute as "SS" (i.e. String Set).

However, you don't need to define the non-key attributes while creating the table as DynamoDB is a NoSQL database. Also, DynamoDB doesn't allow to define the non-key attributes of a table which creating the table.

It would throw **validation exception** when you try to define any attribute which is not part of the key schema.

For the above mentioned reason, **String set "SS"** can't be part of table creation script (as it is not going to be part of key schema).

> Primary key attribute (i.e. partition and sort key) must be defined as
>   type string, number, or binary.
>
> When you create a table or a secondary index, you must specify the
>   names and data types of each primary key attribute (partition key and
>   sort key). Furthermore, each primary key attribute must be defined as
>   type string, number, or binary.
>
> DynamoDB is a NoSQL database, and is schemaless, which means that,
>   other than the primary key attributes, you do not need to define any
>   attributes or data types at table creation time.